# Do we need N/A for daily summary in timeline?

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, timeline

In the post's timeline for the "daily summary" item, I always see the "N/A", [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/302471/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries):

> [image: timeline votes]

Is there really a reason to print it? Can we just omit this like for the "Suggested edits" item on the picture above?

Comment: on a related note, it would be nice to see who proposed the suggested edit in timeline... Now, we could only see the user's name if the suggestion was accepted, but not rejected. I would like to see user's name even when the suggestion was rejected.